# setInterval and prototype error

Tags: javascript, this, setinterval, prototype-programming

I am trying to do a shakeEffect, but i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
setTimeout.elementsCollection.style.position shake.js:66
```

The line 66 is:

```
this.elementsCollection[ i ].style.left = parseInt( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
```

And the complete code:

```
Shake.prototype.shakeEffect = function(){
       if( this.elementsCollection.length != false ){
              var positions = this.shakePosition.split( '|' );
              for( var i = 0; i < this.elementsCollection.length; ++i ){
                     this.elementsCollection[ i ].style.position = 'relative';
                     this.effectInterval = setInterval( function( elementsCollection ) {
                            for( var x = 0; x < positions.length; ++x ){
                                   switch( positions[ x ] ){
                                          case 'left':
                                                 this.elementsCollection[ i ].style.left = -Math.abs( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                                                 break;
                                          case 'right':
                                                 this.elementsCollection[ i ].style.left = parseInt( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                                                 break;
                                          case 'top':
                                          case 'up':
                                                 this.elementsCollection[ i ].style.top = -Math.abs( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                                                 break;
                                          case 'down':
                                                 this.elementsCollection[ i ].style.top = parseInt( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                                                 break;
                                   }
                            }
                     } , this.getInterval() );
                     setTimeout( function(){
                            return function(){
                                   clearInterval( this.effectInterval );
                                   this.elementsCollection[ i ].style.position = null;
                            }
                     } , this.getTimeout() );
              }
       }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A couple things, you can't send parameters in the function in setInterval. You have to do this:

```
setInterval(function (elementsCollection) { alert(elementsCollection) }, 1000 /*delay*/, array)
```

so this should work:

```
this.effectInterval = setInterval( function( elementsCollection ) {
                        for( var x = 0; x < positions.length; ++x ){
                               switch( positions[ x ] ){
                                      case 'left':
                                             elementsCollection[ i ].style.left = -Math.abs( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                                             break;
                                      case 'right':
                                             elementsCollection[ i ].style.left = parseInt( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                                             break;
                                      case 'top':
                                      case 'up':
                                             elementsCollection[ i ].style.top = -Math.abs( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                                             break;
                                      case 'down':
                                             elementsCollection[ i ].style.top = parseInt( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                                             break;
                               }
                        }
                 } , this.getInterval(), this.elementsCollection );
                 setTimeout( function(elementsCollection){
                        return function(){
                               clearInterval( this.effectInterval );
                               elementsCollection[ i ].style.position = null;
                        }
                 } , this.getTimeout(), this.elementsCollection );
```

Comment: + thx, I didn't know that you can send params to the setTimeout/setInterval callbacks that way. nice:)

Comment: in fact, the objects have elementsCollection yes, if I had not even if they would be entering

Answer (score 0):

the setTimeout/setInterval callback is executed in a different context than your object, and when it's executed the `this` keyword does not refer to your object.
Make a variable that refers to the instance and use it instead of `this` in the callback :

```
// ... code
var self = this;
setTimeout( function(){
    return function(){
        clearInterval( self.effectInterval );
        self.elementsCollection[ i ].style.position = null;
    }
 } , this.getTimeout() );
 // ... code
```

When the `this.effectInterval` callback is executed, the `i` value is always the last value of the loop.
Try for yourself:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) 
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(i);},10);
```

The result is not as expected, because the function executes after the loop is finished and the variable `i` has the value of the loop limit.
The right way to pass variables to a cabback functin for setTimeout/setInterval is something like :

```
function mySetTimeout(args,callback,time){
    return setTimeout(function(){
        callback.apply({},args);
    },time); 
};
```

and then you can use it like :

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) 
    mySetTimeout([i],function(i){console.log(i);},10);
```

So, if you use the special `mySetTimeout` function and, of course, the similar `mySetInterval`, your problematic code can be rewritten as follows:

```
this.effectInterval = mySetInterval([i] function( i ) {
    for( var x = 0; x < positions.length; ++x ){
           switch( positions[ x ] ){
                  case 'left':
                         self.elementsCollection[ i ].style.left = -Math.abs( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                         break;
                  case 'right':
                         self.elementsCollection[ i ].style.left = parseInt( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                         break;
                  case 'top':
                  case 'up':
                         self.elementsCollection[ i ].style.top = -Math.abs( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                         break;
                  case 'down':
                         self.elementsCollection[ i ].style.top = parseInt( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';
                         break;
           }
    }
} , this.getInterval() );
```

Comment: Error continue, but now is this:

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    self shake.js:66

Line 66:

    this.elementsCollection[ i ].style.left = parseInt( Math.random() * 20 ) + 'px';